# Calculate percentage of values in list that were found?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a query such as:-

`SELECT id FROM Table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4);`

How can I then have SQL return a value which is the percentage of the values in that list that were found in the table, i.e. 0.75 or 75? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of id's which exist in the table, use `count(distinct id)` or `count(id)` depending on the uniqueness of id in the table. Divide the count by the total number of id's being passed in if you know it beforehand (like 4 in this case).

```
select 1.0*count(distinct id)/4 as pct_in_table 
from Table 
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```